# How to Set Execution Level for .Net application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to set execution level for .Net application to run with administrator privileges when it is run in normal User account on Win XP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code requires an elevated privilege to access registry. However there is just a fragment of code that requires these extra permission. To handle such scenarios impersonation is used i.e. you will execute this application as normal user only but that particular piece of code will be executed as if you were an Administrator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx